# How can I rearrange rows in a sheet into columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a list of cases.

Each row represents a status change with its own timestamp.

Each case can have types, such as water, gas, electricity, all with the same case ID.

How can I group into 1 single row, per type, all of the different status changes with their respective dates.

It doesnt matter if its excel or google sheets.

I'm attaching an example file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UykuqUzRRKFU4BadVvRvHNclSIu6knQ6sAhkH0rIVGs/edit?usp=sharing

I tried maybe with a pivot table but was unsuccesful.

Comment: Questions on this site should be self-contained. Considering this add the sample data and show what you have tried directly into the question body. Also questions on this site should be specific, so choose one, Excel, or Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Power Query.
Here is one way:
*Read the code and code comments to understand the algorithm*

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table28"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Username", type text}, {"Company", type text}, {"CASE ID", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Case Type", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Status Changed From", type text}, 
        {"Status Changed To", type text}, {"Days Since Created", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Time In Previous Status", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Time Between Notes", Int64.Type}, {"Provider", type text}}),

//delete unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Username", "Days Since Created", "Time In Previous Status", "Time Between Notes", "Provider"}),

//Group by {Company, CASE ID & Case Type}
//then aggregate each subgroup into a single row
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Company", "CASE ID", "Case Type"}, {
        {"theRow", (t)=>let

            #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(t,{"Company", "CASE ID", "Case Type"}),
            #"Reorder Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Status Changed From","Status Changed To","Date"}),

            #"New Column Names" = List.Repeat(Table.ColumnNames(#"Reorder Columns"),Table.RowCount(#"Reorder Columns")),
            #"New Column Numbers" = List.ReplaceMatchingItems(List.Accumulate(List.Numbers(0, Table.RowCount(#"Reorder Columns")),{}, (state, current)=>
                state & List.Repeat({Text.From(current)},3)),{{"0",null}}),
            #"New Fields" = List.Transform(List.Zip({#"New Column Names",#"New Column Numbers"}), each Text.Combine(_,"_")),
            Row = List.Accumulate({0..3},{}, (state, current)=> state & Record.ToList(#"Reorder Columns"{current})),
            #"New Row" = Record.FromList(Row,#"New Fields")
            in #"New Row"
        }}),

//expand the column of records to new rows
//Get new column names from the Field Names of the first Record
    colNames = Record.FieldNames(#"Grouped Rows"[theRow]{0}),
    #"Expand Records" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Grouped Rows","theRow",colNames),

//create list of data types for each new column, then set them
    dataTypes = List.Repeat({type text, type text, type date},List.Count(colNames)/3),
    colTypes = List.Zip({colNames,dataTypes}),
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expand Records",colTypes)
in
    typeIt
```

***Original Table From your uploaded Excel Sheet***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you agree to have an output like this, with the first 5 columns of general data and then the changes:

[image]

You can set two formulas like this:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(Data!B1:K,"select B,C,D,H,K,count(C) group by B,C,D,H,K",1),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col1 is not null",1)
```

And in F2:

```
=SCAN(,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,q,
TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(
FILTER(Data!E2:G10,Data!B2:B10=INDEX(A2:A,q),Data!C2:C10=INDEX(B2:B,q),Data!D2:D10=INDEX(C2:C,q))))))
```

I changed those columns in order to be able to add as many columns as changes there are in each of the cases without trouble. Let me know if that's helpful. Here you have my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CMK16PgFPfXzPl6_o_cLSGfLuRMr0rlhj8UuZHrX20Q/edit#gid=163008891) where I tried that:

Comment: I added more data into my sample, and it stopped working :(

Comment: My formula was limited to a certain range due to your original data. I created a copy and expanded the rows of queries and filters and they work! You can check it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-XaQjxeWj-FNaxttOmr7QYtlMwG42rX22tOyLQGPbJA/edit?usp=drivesdk